# How can i add extension to browser from ExtJs application

Tags: extjs, google-chrome-extension

How can i add extension to browser from  my application (Extjs).

For eg: clicking on a button should add extension to chrome browser.
 On click of it(extension) application should be launched.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you want to add extension or call an extension from your application.

Comment: @Cyril Thanks for your reply.
I want to add extension

Answer (score 0):

You can do inline installation: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation

There are a few things you have to setup to do this, the documentation should walk you through them.